# How often do you need to water the flower on the first floor of You in Wonderland?

Tags: persona-q

After you get the watering can you can return to a flower earlier in the labyrinth and water it. After watering it the first time It says you should return later to water it. I left the labyrinth and came back and the event was still there but I was not able to water it again. I forgot to return after that point and had beaten the labyrinth. I then went back again and the event was gone. I haven't gone back since to check it.

Do you just need to water it every time you come back to the labyrinth before you beat it or is it once per labyrinth or once per You In Wonderland floor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From experience, you can only water it every time you enter the labyrinth (after leaving it, of course) and eventually the plant will bloom.

After this, a flower will have dropped from the stem where you take it. It'll be Plum Potpourri.

```
THIS EVENT IS NOT COMPULSORY
```

It is an accessory. If you gather enough of the specific materials, you can buy it yourself in the Workshop.

Don't worry, the event is optional, it's nothing important.